# Invoke-ASCmd: use without UserCode/Password within a Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-analysis-services

I want to make use of the Invoke-ASCmd without UserCode/Password within a Devops pipeline.
Now the code looks like:

```
   $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
   $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securePassword)
   
   $delQuery = '{ "delete": { "object": { "database": "' + $asModelName + '" } } }'
   Invoke-ASCmd -Query $delQuery -TenantId $tenantId -Server $analysisServicesServer -Credential $credential
```

I want to get rid of the usercode/password combination and use the integrated security
Is it possible that the Invoke-ASCmd can use this kind of authentication?

Running it from a devops pipeline I get an error like:
Invoke-ASCmd : Authentication failed: User ID and Password are required when user interface is not available.

Comment: As it said: `User ID and Password are required when user interface is not available`

Comment: Meaning that you must still use a usercode password to deploy and refresh the model?
Invoke-Sqlcmd has an extra AccessToken parameter when provided it uses it from the Managed Identity or the Azure CLI logged in user....